# CSS Popup Position (top & left not working)

Tags: css, popup, positioning

I've followed the [tutorial url](http://www.pat-burt.com/web-development/how-to-do-a-css-popup-without-opening-a-new-window/) to get a popup working:

I have one caveat though.  Sometimes the pages it will be popping up from are really, really long.  The code in the tutorial has it popping up in the center.  Vertically, this is not acceptable. I'm trying to get it to pop up in the center, but at the very top.  I've used top: 0px; and for testing purposes left: 0px; (and a few others) but it seems to matter not.  Always pops up in the center.

You can take a look at the latest one I've done [here](https://www.gamengai.com/popup.php#)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mind making a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your top and left values are being ignored in the CSS because whatever script you're using to make the popup happen is applying the styles inline directly to the popup. So you should look through that script and find where it's applying the styles, then change it there.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  If it was 1998 I would have the time to go through and completely redesign the sight.  It's 2012 and I have 3 mouths to feed, so I can only do so much.

Thanks for the tip on the script. It was a copy & paste.  I do kinda see that now.

Comment: @PaulEngland You should invest time in learning how to code your layouts with CSS the right way. It really will make things easier in the long run. Sorry I was abrasive about the tables, it's late and I really hate seeing those. I wish we could go through and demolish every tutorial that uses that method.

Comment: I agree, but it just does not make logistical sense for me now. The code base of the site is REALLY old.  I admit that.  In a perfect world I would have time to go through and change it, but I simply do not have time.  

I'm making changes now that will give my users immediate gratification.  This is a process that generates funds for the site.  I made a duct tape solution for it about 18 months ago when something out of my hands changed, and am just now doing a proper one.  Assuming that's done I can figure out some other stuff, but honestly it was dumb luck I was able to get this much time.

Comment: ...I should book mark this thread to remind me to update it though. ;)

Comment: I didn't necessarily mean for this site. I meant for future sites you make. If this site works the way it is and you won't gain anything by changing it then by all means leave it.

Comment: Ah, yeah.  I may or may not be doing one for a friend coming up.  I know I won't be using this as a template. ;)

Answer (score 0):

#### Your technique is very old and not the right way!

What happens in your case is, you have considered the page's height and width for calculating the center position. If you can change it like:

```
popUpDiv.style.top = '10%';
```

Just give a try and let me know.

#### Best Suggestion: Use jQuery! :)

But, what I have followed is from Queness, which is still more simple.

**Tutorial:** [Simple jQuery Modal Window Tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial) and [Live Demo](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/modal/jquery-modal-window.html).

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  You can take a peak at the link above to see that the syntax is correct.

Comment: Hey, I said the technique is very old. And syntax is correct. But it uses your page height. So, what are you getting when you use `10%`?

Comment: Nothing.  I had to use the suggestions below.  "important" works.  The right way is probably to edit the Javascript which I will try to get to.  I'd like to update the design (I've not done so in years) but I simply do not have the time to.  This is site is very much on my back burner, but it's still used so I will make small fixes where I can.

Comment: Yeah, `!important` works, but many people won't recommend it for certain reasons. But, why don't you try using the Simple jQuery Modal Window? Its good and easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `css` for `#popUpDiv` do `top : 0 !important` and you will find your popup box at the top. It is because javascript is calculating the `top` position and its overwriting your css style. Hope this helps.